# Spherical Polar co-ordinate to cartesian co-ordinate conversion

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

Is there any method to convert a data set from spherical polar coordinate system to cartesian coordinate system in python?

--- Please Help

Comment: You could try pyproj

Answer (score 2):

Looking at wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system the standard conversion is:

[image]

You need to be in radial coordinates (theta, phi). If not use `math.radians` on theta and phi.

```
import math

def polar2cart(r, theta, phi):
    return [
         r * math.sin(theta) * math.cos(phi),
         r * math.sin(theta) * math.sin(phi),
         r * math.cos(theta)
    ]
```

Comment: suppose I have the data in following format:
dimension of 'X' is (100X200);
dimension of 'Y' is (100X200);
dimension of 'Z' is (75);
dimension of 'data' is (100X200);

now I want to make the the 3D plot. how can I do that.

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you mean by the dimension on 'X' is (100x200). Do you mean that x takes values between 100 and 200?

Comment: No. I mean X is a matrix of 100X200 dimension

Comment: Okay but how are you representing a point in 3D? (X[0-100][0-200], Y[0-100][0-200], Z[0-75])? The dimension on Z does not match X and Y.

Comment: Actually have a data in spherical polar co-ordinate system now I converted the data into cartesian system. So now I have X Y Z and data. Now I want to plot the data in XYZ system that is cartesian system. The plot will be a 3D plot with colourbar which will represent the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to write your own code, take a look at the `astropy` package: http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/. Specifically, [`cartesian_to_spherical()`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.cartesian_to_spherical.html#astropy.coordinates.cartesian_to_spherical) and [`spherical_to_cartesian()`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.spherical_to_cartesian.html#astropy.coordinates.spherical_to_cartesian) should do the trick for you.